# Magento 2.4.5-p2 admin grid are stuck on loading until refresh the page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

After login in Magento admin, grids are stuck on loading. It's continuously loading until we refresh the page. While the grids are stuck on loading we are not even able to open any other tabs from admin.

For example : if I open sale -> order grid [ its stuck on loading ], then other tabs are not working either. Sometimes it happens after login in Magento admin and tabs are not working - sales - catalogs etc, none of them are working nor are clickable.

We have done the following till now to solve this issue, but the issue is fixed : We check all the log files and there are no errors. We try removing `ui_bookmark` table, but it doesn't work for us either. We try to debug the error but we find nothing, we are on production mode and we change the mode into developer to find the issue in frontend or in log, but again we got nothing in log files and there is no error in frontend.

Could anyone please suggest the solution to fix this issue so that we can proceed further ?

Comment: Try again after disabling if there are any custom extensions.

Comment: Thanks but we not using any custom extension for this & i run di compile command but am not getting any error in that

Answer (score 2):

Probably related to a bug that is caused by Adobe and their tracking tool. Try the following:

```
bin/magento config:set admin/usage/enabled 0;
bin/magento cache:clean;
```

More info can be found here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37618#issuecomment-1592991014

Comment: You're welcome! Please select my answer as the solution so others will know :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case these problems came all of a sudden when logging to in Magento backend (2.4.5) with Microsoft Edge.
After trying every solution proposed on different Magento forums without any improvement I almost gave up.
Instead I tried to log in to Magento backend using Google Chrome and to my surprise everything worked fine using this browser.
An examination of the extensions used in Microsoft Edge gave the answer.
After uninstalling the "Karma" extension in Edge everything worked as it should again.
The Karma browser extension is a shopping extension that search for coupons, pricedrops and back in stock when shopping on the web.
Apparently the extension somehow crashes the Magento backend on database intensive tabs like sales, products and customers.
So turn of the Karma extension or uninstall it and see if the problem with a spinning wheel goes away.